# Jquery Highlight Effect Not Smooth

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

at this url the jquery highlight effect [here](http://www.freeenergymedia.com/?page_id=10) does not fade out smoothly as it does in [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight#options). How can this be fixed? Thanks. It is simple code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#content').effect("highlight", {color:"#0101DF"}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: run it on load instead, your page is not completely load when the animation starts

Comment: could it be because your background color and the highlight color don't match exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it when the page is completely loaded. other stuff on the page are slowing down your animation

```
window.onload = function(){
   $('#content').effect("highlight", {color:"#0101DF"}, 1000);
};
```